# Is it possible to use Enterprise Java Beans in a django project?

Tags: java, django, jython, enterprise, javabeans

I've seen that it is possible to run the django web framework on a GlassFish application server. Is it also possible to use a simple Enterprise Java Bean in a django project which runs on the basis of Jython? My idea is to have a django website for the frontend and Java EE in the backend (to manage the database access, etc.). Does anyone have experience with that?

Comment: Django has a perfectly fine ORM, why on earth would you want to use Java for the backend?

Comment: @exelian, not only Java, its EJB 3.0, I think is a good question. Benny what kind of bussines process are you doing with ejbs, just serving webservices operations or something more complex?

Answer (score 0):

A possibly easier variant would be to expose the EJB functionality using REST or possibly SOAP to get around interface problems between jython and java rather than do the call directly.

Comment: I need to do it for college. So is it possible or not? If yes... How? I know that one can use EJBs with Ruby on Rails. But I need to use them in django. I want to use business logic (which has been always implemented in EJBs) in a new django project.